# Matrix operations in OpenCV for Android

Tags: java, android, objective-c, opencv, matrix

There's an iOS app written in Objective-C that has image processing code that i'm now implementing in Android version.

iOS source code has following code:

```
Mat myMask;
Mat morph;
dilate(longEdge, morph, element1);
...
Mat mask = myMask.mul(1-morph);
```

Question is - how to write this part of code `(1 - morph)` in Java.

Does this equals to `morph.inv()` or some other function in Mat or Core class?

Thank you in advance.